# Counting the number of cells in a column that contain a specific string (in R)

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataframe in R. I would like to count the number of cells in a column that contain a specific string.

Using the example data below, I want to count how many cells in the column a contain the string "purple." (2)

I imagine something like this: `sum(df$a %contains% "purple")`

```
a <- c("red, white", "white", "blue, purple", "purple")
b <- c("white", "white, yellow", "purple", "purple, blue, yellow")
df <- data.table(a, b)
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `%like%` i.e. `sum(df$a %like% "purple")#
[1] 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grepl` (only works if there are no more than one occurrence per string):

```r
sum(grepl("purple", a))
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do with `str_count`

```
sum(stringr::str_count(df$a, pattern = "purple"))
```